# LIBCURL compilation failure on ARM 64 machine using cross compiler arm-octasic-linux-gnueabi

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, libcurl, arm64

I am trying to install compile & install LibCurl on ARM 64 machine.
Cross compiler used is octasic/01.09.04/sysroots/x86_64-octasicsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-octasic-linux-gnueabi/arm-octasic-linux-gnueabi-gcc.

Below is the machine detail:

```
uname -a
Linux labadmin 5.15.0-71-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 18 09:00:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Getting below compilation failure:

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking whether to disable dependency on -lrt... (assumed no)
checking whether to enable ECH support... no
checking for path separator... :
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc... /opt/octasic/01.09.04/sysroots/x86_64-octasicsdk- 
linux/usr/bin/arm-octasic-linux-gnueabi/arm-octasic-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in 
`PKG/curl':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
LibCurl arm_64 Build failed..!!
```

Please suggest.

Comment: "See `config.log' for more details"